# The probability upper bound on the ratio of the eigenvalues

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Consider a $N\times N$ normalized matrix sample from GOE (the definition see [https://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~leticia/TEACHING/Master2019/GOE-cuentas.pdf](https://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/%7Eleticia/TEACHING/Master2019/GOE-cuentas.pdf)). If we apply the following result of the edge of the spectrum,

> If we denote the $k$ largest eigenvalues by $\lambda_N,\lambda_{n-1},··· ,\lambda_{N-k+1}, $ then for Gaussian ensembles the joint distribution function of rescaled eigenvalues has the limit:
> $$
> \lim_{N\to\infty}P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-2)\le s_1,\dots, N^{2/3}(\lambda_{N-k+1}-2)\le s_k)=F_{\beta, k}(s_1,\dots, s_k)
> $$
> where $F_{\beta, k}(s_1,\dots, s_k)$ is the Tracy-Widom distribution.

then we will get the following results by continuous mapping theorem:
$$\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-k+1}=O_P(N^{-2/3})$$

Now, if we ordering all eigenvalues by
$|\sigma_N|\ge |\sigma_{N-1}|\ge \dots \ge |\sigma_1|$.

**I would like have the similar result that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists  constants $C>0,\alpha>0$ so that
$$
P\left(N^{\alpha}\left(\frac{|\sigma_N|}{|\sigma_{N-k+1}|}-1\right)\le C\right)\ge 1-\epsilon
$$**

I am not if we can take $\alpha=2/3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tracy-Widom distribution says that the level spacing near the edge of the spectrum at $\pm 2$ is of order $N^{-2/3}$, hence we may define
$$|\sigma_N|\equiv 2+N^{-2/3}\delta,\;\;|\sigma_{N-k+1}|\equiv 2+N^{-2/3}\delta',$$
with $\delta,\delta'$ of order $N^0$. Now consider
$$\Delta=N^{2/3}\left(\frac{|\sigma_N|}{|\sigma_{N-k+1}|}-1\right)=\frac{\delta-\delta'}{2+N^{-2/3}\delta'}=\tfrac{1}{2}(\delta-\delta')+{\cal O}(N^{-2/3}).$$
Normalisation requires that $\lim_{C\rightarrow\infty}P(\Delta\leq C)=1$, so for each $\epsilon>0$ we can find a constant $C>0$ so that
$$P(\Delta\leq C)\geq 1-\epsilon,$$
which is the desired inequality. The constant $C$ will depend on $\epsilon$, but it will be independent of $N$ for large $N$.

Comment: Thanks. But I am a little bit confused about if we can still apply the Tracy-Widom law of $k$ largest eigenvalue after taking the absolute value. We know that the largest eigenvalue is near 2. But why $|\sigma_N|$ is still near 2? Also, can you explain why we have $|\sigma_{N-k+1}=2+O(N^{-2/3})$? Thanks!

Comment: Tracy-Widom applies to the eigenvalues near $+2$ and near $-2$, these have a spacing that is of order $N^{-2/3}$ or smaller; taking the absolute value will give you quantities near $+2$, still with a spacing of order $N^{-2/3}$ or smaller; for fixed $k$ this applies to any $|\sigma_{N-k+1}|$ at large $N$, so $|\sigma_{N-k+1}|=2+{\cal O}(N^{-2/3})$.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask if there is some relevant reference about the Tracy-Widom law for the absolute value of eigenvalue?

Comment: no one has considered that, but it's obvious what happens: the levels near $-2$ are statistically independent from the levels near $+2$; so when you take the absolute value you just superimpose two independent Tracy-Widom distributed sequences; this means there will be no level repulsion, that is the main difference, but for the estimate you are seeking that does not matter.

Comment: Thanks. So we can also find a constant $C'>0$ so that $P(\Delta\ge C')\ge 1-\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: Sorry for one more question. So Tracy-Widom law is the joint limiting distribution of the $k$-largest eigenvalues. It seems that we also need this law for $k$ bottom eigenvalues? Dose this one still hold?

Comment: Tracy-Widom applies to both edges of the spectrum, the upper edge near 2, and the lower edge near -2.